# change 3-way switch to combo switch & outlet

Tags: multiway-switch

[image: Text]

I hope this diagram explains my question.

change 3-way switch to combo switch & outlet.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/RHA14csyN3eKtqTM7

Comment: Your link points at an empty photo album...

Answer (score 1):

With the wiring as shown in your diagram you cannot add an outlet. You need a neutral and a hot for the outlet to work. Both switches have two travelers that won't help. The third wire in each switch is either a load wire to the light or a hot wire, but no neutral. You would need to run new wire.

Comment: thanks for that answer. I was afraid that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

### Nope.

The 3 wires you have are:

- Traveler 1
- Traveler 2
- Switched-Hot

The 2 additional wires you'll need for the outlet are:

- Always-hot
- Neutral

They're just not there.

### The switch doesn't support it anyway

That switch would also need to be a 3-way switch, which it is not.

### There might be a way with smart switches.

If the 3-way switches were converted to smart switches, depending on the switch, a side-effect would be completely re-tasking those 3 wires to be always-hot, neutral, and data-comm.  *And look at that! Two of those are just what you need*.

Comment: thanks for that answer. I was afraid that was the case.

Comment: @MarkZanetti Yes, some smart switches even have *wireless* remotes, which would allow you to dedicate the 1-gang switch location entirely to receptacle, and have a wireless remote switch stuck to the wall right next to it. Most are styled to resemble normal switches.